# .htaccess 404 redirection and keep query string

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404

I try to redirect all http query on my website like "http://www.example.com/abcd" (that generate 404 error) to "http://www.example.com/error.php?e=abcd" (to keep the abcd request in a database)

I tried to find a way with .htaccess file, but nothing work fine :(

I tried something like this :

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.example.com/error.php?e=$1
```

I know I have to do some RewriteCond and RewriteRule stuffs, but I don't know how to use is properly

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should remove `http://...` to avoid full redirection i.e.:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /error.php?e=403
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php?e=404
```

Now you can get original 404 causing URI using:

```
$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]=/abcd
```

while `$_GET['e']` will give you code `404`,`403` etc in case you want to have some logic based on this.